# Node, or HTMLElement are not functions?

Tags: dom

I had expected,

```
Node.__proto__===Function.prototype
```

But this is not true.

What is `Node.__proto__, or HTMLElement.__proto__`?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: But [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node) and [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLElement) *aren't* functions. What made you think that they were?

Answer (score 1):

In JS even primary data types are Objects. This is why you can do for example `var.toString` or `arr.length`. They have some basic methods attached to them.

For example:
`Node.__proto__` has: `__defineGetter__`, `__defineSetter__`, `constructor`, `toString()` and so on.

Comment: What you are saying is true, because `Node.__proto__.__proto__===Object.prototype`. But what is `Node.__proto__`?